# Join two tables with key in common and show on a datagrid c# linq

Tags: c#, linq

I need to join the two tables of a DataGrid, but I only want the values with the same id (idviagem is pk in table idviagem and is fk in table idpassageiro)

I don't know how to do the query, in that moment I only take the table tbpassageiro on the grid, and I want to join them on DataGrid when the keys are equals

```
using (checkinEntities1 db = new checkinEntities1())
{

    var qcheckin = (from c in db.tbpassageiro
                    join g in db.tbviagem on c.idviagem equals g.idviagem
                    where c.idviagem == g.idviagem
                    select c).ToList();

     gridpass.ItemsSource = qcheckin;

}
```

The binding I know 100% is correct (some values from table passageiro and the other Biding values from table tbviagem)

This what I want to do:

[image]

Comment: What does the code do now? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: See the image that i Posted ... I'm learning c# at the moment ....

Comment: @GuilhermeMonteiro I'm sorry but your question is not much clear, do you have problem in getting data from two tables (in Linq) or putting result in data grid view ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want columns from both tables, then you have to create a view model for the columns which you want from both tables.

```
using (checkinEntities1 db = new checkinEntities1())
```

{

```
var qcheckin = (from c in db.tbpassageiro
                join g in db.tbviagem on c.idviagem equals g.idviagem
                where c.idviagem == g.idviagem
                select new viewModelName()
                {
                    //get the column values here like
                    Hora = c.Hora,
                    Partida = g.Partida
                }).ToList();

 gridpass.ItemsSource = qcheckin;
```

}

Hope this will give you the answer you are looking for.